# ActiveRecord column decimal default value

Tags: activerecord, rails-activerecord, bigdecimal

I have a tableless class defined like this:

```
class MyClass
  class MyClassRules < ActiveRecord::Base
    column :a, :integer
    column :b, :boolean
    column :c, :datetime
    column :d, :decimal, :precision => 10, :scale => 4
    column :e, :string
  end
end
```

The object of type `MyClassRules` gets automatically built when I instantiate an object of type `MyClass`, and it is stored serialized in a single column in the `my_class` table called `rules` and accessible from `my_obj.rules`.  So I can also make calls like `my_obj.rules.a`.

The issue I'm having is the default value of the decimal column.  Without providing values when I build the object, I would expect all values to default to nil.  Instead, what I get is this:

```
#<MyClass::MyClassRules
  a: nil,
  b: nil,
  c: nil,
  d: #<BigDecimal:7fce8f295620,'0.0',9(9)>,
  e: nil
>
```

Indeed, most of them default to nil, but `decimal` defaults to `0.0`.  I've even tried passing a `:default => nil` param to the declaration, and that does nothing.

How can I force a decimal column to default to nil?

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question.  Modifying the class to initialize the values to nil works:

```
class MyClass
  class MyClassRules < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_initialize :init

    column :a, :integer
    column :b, :boolean
    column :c, :datetime
    column :d, :decimal, :precision => 10, :scale => 4
    column :e, :string

    def init
      self.d = nil
    end
  end
end
```

Seems unnecessary, but it gets the job done.