# ActiveRecord: Cleanest way to change default value of existing column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

### Background

My database contains two tables, which I created with `rails g migration`.

One table contains tv programs with several columns of data describing each program. One column is called :watchlist. I forgot to set a default value of :watchlist to false, as each new show should have a watchlist value of false. On my frontend, I want to be able to toggle this value from false to true (the act of adding a program to a watchlist changes the value from false to true).

### What I've Tried

I am using a Rails API for my backend, so I consulted the [documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column_default) and tried change_column_default using this code:

```
rails change_column_default :program, :watchlist, from: nil, to: false
```

but got this error:

```
Don't know how to build task 'change_column_default' (See the list of available tasks with `rails --tasks`)
```

I tried `rails --tasks` but did not see what I needed in the list generated.

Searching through other questions, I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123285/activerecord-column-decimal-default-value), but would rather not do this on the model if I don't have to.

Current (incorrect) migration. `:watchlist` should be `t.boolean :watchlist, default: false`

```
class CreatePrograms < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :programs do |t|
      t.string :url
      t.string :name
      t.string :network
      t.string :image
      t.boolean :watchlist

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Program model

```
class Program < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments

  validates :name, :network, presence: true

end
```

Program serializer

```
class ProgramSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :network, :image, :watchlist

  has_many :comments
end
```

### Recap of Questions

1. Can I update one column in an existing table from command line?
2. If no, how should I alter my current code?

#### Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `change_column_default` method in migration file.

1. Generate migration file

   ```
   rails g migration add_default_false_to_watchlist_for_programs
   ```
2. add `change_column_default` method to migration file

   ```
   class AddDefaultFalseToWatchlistForPrograms < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def change
       change_column_default :programs, :watchlist, from: nil, to: false
     end
   end
   ```
3. run `rails db:migrate`

Answer (score 1):

that is because `change_column_default` is not a rake task

- you need to generate a migration `rails g migration add_default_value_to_watchlist_for_programs` this will generate a migration file.
- then you need to add the line that tells active record to set a default value in the migration we have created
  `change_column_default :programs, :watchlist, from: nil, to: false`
- then you need to run the migration by `rails db:migrate`

Comment: Out curiosity, how is this different from the earlier answer?